# Android Listview item long click don't respond CheckBox event

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

***This is what I want to achieve function：***
The Listview item style use custom layout XML file. When I long press on the listview item, the checkbox is VISIBLE and can respond to a click event.
[image]

*But when I click the listview or checkbox, it doesn't have any response event.Why?*

This is part of my **List Adapter** code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = null;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (null != convertView && convertView instanceof LinearLayout) {
            view = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        } else {
            view = View.inflate(notifyFragment.getActivity(),R.layout.item_notify, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notify_title);
            holder.timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notify_timestamp);
            holder.content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notify_content);
            holder.cbox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.notify_cbox);
            holder.markFlag = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.notify_markflag);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        Item_Notify inform_item = notify_list.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(inform_item.get_title());
        holder.timestamp.setText(inform_item.get_timestamp());
        holder.content.setText(inform_item.get_content());

        if (isShow) {
            holder.cbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Boolean flag = notifyFragment.recodeStatu.get(position);
            if (flag == null) {
                holder.cbox.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                holder.cbox.setChecked(flag);
            }
        } else {
            holder.cbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView content;
        TextView timestamp;
        CheckBox cbox;
        ImageView markFlag;
    }
```

This is **Click Event**:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                listAdapter.isShow = true;
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                ll_notify_action.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (listAdapter.isShow) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.notify_cbox);
                    boolean isCheck = !cb.isChecked();
                    if (isCheck) {
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        count--;
                    }
                    btn_del.setText("Delete(" + count + ")");
                    recodeStatu.put(position, isCheck);
                    cb.setChecked(isCheck);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "click " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: @Kelvin u need to put checkbox in getview() method  and from that u need to change in model class with boolean.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood this correctly, but you need to attach an OnclickListener to your CheckBox(when is visible), in the ListAdapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood right, i think that you forgot to insert in the parent layout of the checkbox of `List Adapter`:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

Something like this (this is a random example so you have to follow your layout, i created this only to make you able to understand where you have to put that information):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right, as the ListViewItem has an ClickEventListener any embedded Views won't get events such as click.

Comment: How do I solve this problem? Can you give me any advice?